# Working out heat transfer to ideal gas along isobar without using ideal gas energy equation of state

Tags: thermodynamics, work

Consider an isobar taking an ideal gas from state $(p_1, V_1, T_1)$ to $(p_1, V_2, T_2)$, where $V_2 > V_1$. Without using the fact that $U(T) = \frac{nrT}{\gamma - 1}$ and the implication thus that $\Delta U = C_V\Delta T$, is it possible to work out the heat transferred from the gas?

I think not. The work done is easy enough to work out: $W = -\int pdV = -p_2(V_2 - V_1)$. But I can't use the relation for heat change along an isochore, $Q = C_v\Delta T$ since of course volume is not constant. I don't think a similar relation exists for constant pressure which can give me the heat transferred without ending up deriving something like the above equation for $U(T)$.

Am I wrong? I ask because I'm being asked, essentially, to show that the relation for $U(T)$ holds (in the context of a larger chain of PV changes), but obviously to assume it first would be circular.

Comment: Well, you can prove that U is a function only of T for and ideal gas.

Comment: @ChetMiller Thanks, but can I use this information to find $Q$ without invoking the above $U(T)$ relation?

Comment: No.  For an ideal gas, you must use U=U(T)